# XSL: Is there an easy way to prevent widows?

Tags: xslt, symphony-cms

I was hoping to call ..

```
<xsl:call-template name="widow-fix">
  <with-param name="text" select="text"></with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

And then it would look for the last `space` in the text and replace it with `#160;` when finalized.

---

Should be able to support

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

and

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
```

Please use a different character, like `#` to answer/prove, so the result when I test would be

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing#elit.
```

and

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing#elit.</p>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the input string?

Comment: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.`

Comment: Thx - Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: I'm currently using 1.0 (what comes with http://www.getsymphony.com/ )

Comment: See http://www.2sheds.ru/blog/2007/06/widont-in-xslt-dont-be-a-widow-maker/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All that you need is to replace the last space in every text node:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


<xsl:template match="p | text()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="widow-fix"/>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="* | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="* | @*" mode="widow-fix">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="widow-fix"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="text()[contains(., ' ')]" mode="widow-fix">
    <xsl:call-template name="text">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="text">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>

    <xsl:variable name="substring-before" select="substring-before($text, ' ')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="substring-after"  select="substring-after($text, ' ')"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($substring-after, ' ')">
            <xsl:value-of select="$substring-before"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>

            <xsl:call-template name="text">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$substring-after"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$substring-before"/>
            <!--<xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>-->
            <xsl:text>#</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$substring-after"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The mode="widow-fix" can process both text nodes and paragraphs preserving the enclosing tag.

I used such document as a test source

```
<book>
<p>Highly random content</p>
in this book
</book>
```

which converts to the following

```
<book>
<p>Highly random#content</p>
in this#book
</book>
```

Comment: Glad to know that it was what you needed! That's my first answer here :)

P.S. I have slightly simplified the template for text() in mode="widow-fix".

Comment: Is there a way to make it not insert an element of the name? Currently if I run `<xsl:apply-templates select="solution-headline" mode="widow-fix" />` it will insert `<solution-headline>Lorem ipsum<solution-headline/>` I want `<xsl:text>Lorem ipsum<xsl:text/>`

Comment: You can omit it selecting all the nodes in this element: <xsl:apply-templates select="solution-headline/node()" mode="widow-fix" />

Answer (score 0):

You need "select=text()", and you can do the replacement with one of the xs: string functions, but I wouldn't describe the result as preventing widows.