# XSL: Is there an easy way to prevent widows? (part 2)

Tags: xslt, symphony-cms

Using the solution from [XSL: Is there an easy way to prevent widows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19694667/xsl-is-there-an-easy-way-to-prevent-widows/19794203) makes odd tags in the DOM.

Is there a way to make it not insert an element of the name? Currently if I run

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="solution-headline" mode="widow-fix" />
```

it will insert

```
<solution-headline>Lorem ipsum<solution-headline/>
```

I want it to insert

```
<xsl:text>Lorem ipsum<xsl:text/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the text then the simplest approach would be to apply the widow-fix templates to just the text node children of the `solution-headline` element rather than to the element itself:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="solution-headline/text()" mode="widow-fix" />
```

If you *always* want the widow-fixing to give you just the text and not include the surrounding element, then delete the existing template

```
<xsl:template match="* | @*" mode="widow-fix">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="widow-fix"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Now when you apply the widow-fix templates to `solution-headline` it will use the [default template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) which essentially just does `<xsl:apply-templates mode="widow-fix" />` (i.e. process all child nodes using the same mode) *without* the `copy`, and you'll get all the descendant text nodes processed by the widow-fixing template.

Comment: Is there a way to modify the `widow-fix` mode to always use `text()` ? If you can paste that revised template here I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: @KirkStrobeck I've added a suggestion of one way you could handle that.